# writing an array to a CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to write this

```
var IO=new Array (0x00,0x00,0x00,0x001E,0x001D,0x001B,0x0018,0x0018,0x0016,0x0018,0x001b)
```

from ioreg.js to a CSV file.

So I can build a chart monitoring a electrical current using this componet

http://www.denkovi.com/product/8/snmp-ethernet-controller-with-24-digital-analog-i-o.html

I would like to show the current in real time. Thanks for your help in advance. Eric

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
string tempString = null;
for(i=0;i<IO.size;i++){
   string += IO.get[i] + ";";
 }
```

After this, you write it to a file.